# Where we use inheritance in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

I am beginner in postgreSQL.
In my knowledge, postgreSQL inheritance does not propagate trigger. 
Then what the use of inheritance in psql and what it offers than other databases?

(Following up on [this prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26030806/398670)).

Answer (score 0):

There is one use of inheritance, where you have to use it - it is partitioning - when logically one table is physically split into several smaller tables. Please check documentation at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html